# How to serialize/deserialze a class that implements IEnumerator, IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, ienumerable, ienumerator

Just want to stress out this question is irrelevant of why this technology and why not that. This is related to C# code.

I searched below but none provides solution.

[Serialize a class that implements IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295768/serialize-a-class-that-implements-ienumerable)

[Serialization on classes that implement IEnumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285863/serialization-on-classes-that-implement-ienumerator)

I am working on WCF Rest project in C# which is replacing .NET Remoting communication layer. I use Newtonsoft dll to serialize and de-serialize.

I have a class called `MyDTO` which implements `IEnumerator`, `IEnumerable` which I cannot change since this is old class and many applications in production use them. When I try to serialize `MyDTO` into string I do not get any error/exception message, I just get an empty array like "[]". Can anybody tell how we can serialize/deserialze class that implements `IEnumerator`, `IEnumerable`?

```
public class MyDTO : IEnumerator, IEnumerable
```

**I am calling a method called ABC in OldServer.dll which gives me MyDTO object. I want to convert this to string and again from string to MyDTO.**

Please let me know if you need more information. Please see below for `MyDTO` class which I cannot change:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyDTO : IEnumerator, IEnumerable
{
    #region Inner Types

    internal class MyObjComparer : IComparer<MyObj>
    {
        public int Compare(MyObj x, MyObj y)
        {
            return x.InputCode.CompareTo(y.InputCode);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Variables

    private List<MyObj> myObjList;
    private string selectedObjectMessage;

    private bool containSequenceNo = false;

    private bool sortEnabled;
    private bool filterEnabled;
    private IComparer<MyObj> objectComparer;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public MyDTO()
    {
        this.myObjList = new List<MyObj>();
        this.selectedObjectMessage = string.Empty;
    }

    public MyDTO(List<MyObj> objects)
    {
        this.myObjList = objects;
        this.selectedObjectMessage = string.Empty;
    }

    public MyDTO(IComparer<MyObj> argSortComparer)
        : this()
    {
        this.objectComparer = argSortComparer;
    }

    public MyDTO(List<MyObj> argErrors, IComparer<MyObj> argSortComparer)
        : this(argErrors)
    {
        this.objectComparer = argSortComparer;
    }

    public MyDTO(List<MyObj> argErrors, IComparer<MyObj> argSortComparer, bool argSortEnabled)
        : this(argErrors, argSortComparer)
    {
        this.sortEnabled = argSortEnabled;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string selectedObjectMessage
    {
        get { return this.selectedObjectMessage; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                value = string.Empty;

            this.selectedObjectMessage = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.myObjList.Count; }
    }

    public bool ErrorsContainsSequenceNo
    {
        get { return this.containSequenceNo; }
        set { this.containSequenceNo = value; }
    }

    public List<MyObj> myObjList            
    {                                          
        get { return this.myObjList; }         
        set { this.myObjList = value; } 
    }     

    public MyDTO WithoutEmptyMyObjects
    {
        get
        {
            MyDTO objs = new MyDTO();

            foreach (MyObj obj in this.myObjList)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.InputCode))
                    objs.Add(obj);
            }
            return objs;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

After spending almost a day we decided to write our own method targeting MyDTO which will produce XmlDocument which is serialize. Using that same XmlDocument we will try create MyDTO object. I feel we need to just concentrate on properties that has setters. I will let you know.

Comment: Why are you using WCF Rest instead of ASP.NET Web API or ASP.NET Core? WCF Rest was only meant as a stop-gap measure before ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.. before I joined the company it was decided that in order for us to open up our system .net remoting will be replaced by WCF. After I joined, I did research SOAP vs REST and I recommended REST. It serves our purpose I do not see REST HTTP is not going to be replaced in near/distant future

Comment: You did not answer his actual question. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775132/difference-between-wcf-web-api-wcf-rest-and-web-service)

Comment: Ok.. now I cannot change WCF Rest service to someother since it is already in production..

Comment: I know it's out of scope for this question - but you probably should start planning for swapping that. WCF probably won't be around forever... upgrading things like this should be part of any systems life cycle management. Unless you plan for it to be decommissioned before it becomes an issue ofc

Answer (score 0):

Using the almighty [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

1) Create a contract resolver to serialize/deserialize specific members based on their accessibility, cause by default serialization/deserialization only happens for public members.

```
public class MyContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        .Select(p => base.CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization))
                    .Union(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                               .Select(f => base.CreateProperty(f, memberSerialization)))
                    .ToList();
        props.ForEach(p => { p.Writable = true; p.Readable = true; });
        return props;
    }
}
```

2) Then you can serialize your object like

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver() };

// dtoInstance is your dto instance you wish to serialize.
string serializedDTO = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtoInstance, settings);
```

3) And you can deserialize like

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver() };  

MyDTO deserializedDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDTO>(serializedDTO, settings);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed.. I will try and let you know.

Comment: On further analysis CreateProperties type was Object. I added    Type t = typeof(MyDTO);  var x = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); Now I get few props. But serialize is returning me "[]"